# Databricks python notebook to execute %sql commandlet based on condition

Tags: databricks

I have created a python notebook in Databricks, I have python logic and need to execute a `%sql` commandlet.

Say I wanted to execute that commandlet2 based on a python variable

cmd1

```
EXECUTE_SQL= True
```

cmd2

```
if condition : 
  %sql .....
```

Comment: Since you are using Databricks,it allows you used Sql commands using sql("<query>")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use following Python code (or Scala) to make behavior similar to the `%sql` cell:

```py
if condition:
  display(spark.sql("your-query"))
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can embed variables into the query text.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate which I used is

- Extracted the sql to a different notebook,

  - In my case i don't want any results back
  - Also I am cleaning up the delta tables and deleting contents.

/clean-deltatable-notebook (an sql notebook)

```
delete from <database>.<table>
```

- used the `dbutils.run.notebook()` from the python notebook.

cmd2

```
if condition :
   result = dbutils.run.notebook('<path-of-(clean-deltatable-noetbook)',timeout_seconds = 30)
   print(result)
```

Link on `dbutils.notebook.run()` from [Databricks](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001GHVd5CAH/whats-the-difference-between-run-vs-dbutilsnotebookrun)